# Angular.js ui-router call child states from onEnter() based on authentication with same url as parent

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

You'll probably be able to see what I'm trying to do. I want to `transitionTo()` a child state `onEnter()` the root path. The `auth` resolve determines if a company or user is logged in. It currently seems to go into an infinite loop, but I'm not entirely sure why. Let me know if you can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

```
$stateProvider
  .state "home",
    template: '<ui-view autoscroll="false"/>'
    abstract: true
    url: "/"
    resolve:
      auth: (Auth) -> Auth.loggedIn()
    onEnter: ($state, auth) ->
      if auth.data.user? and auth.data.user
        $state.transitionTo("home.user")
      else if auth.data.company? and auth.data.company
        $state.transitionTo("home.company")

  .state "home.user",
    url: ''
    controller: "UsersController"
    templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('users/ang_search_jobs.html.erb') %>"

  .state "home.company",
    url: ''
    controller: "JobListingCtrl"
    templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('job_listings/ang_full_user_matches.html.erb') %>"
```

Comment: Currently looking into this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/929

Answer (score 0):

If you are right about the infinite loop, I am guessing that the `transitionTo` call is happening before the initial `home` route has completed loading. This would make the `home` state begin loading again.

I would instead either use a controller for the home state with the user data injected, and perform the `transitionTo` from there. Otherwise I would use the router provider `.when()` function and inject the user data into that, performing the `transitionTo` from there.